# Couchdb changes to Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, couchdb, real-time, database-replication

I want to have all of the changes of a `couchdb database` in `kafka` at application run time as they arrive. Is there any reliable existing tool for that?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) tool. Also, [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/product/confluent-platform/) provides [long list](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) of different connectors for Kafka Connect.

I'm not a CouchDB user, but you may choose one of applicable *source* connectors [here](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) or [create](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html) your own Kafka CouchDB source connector.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using confluent.

Comment: So, [Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) is a part of Kafka. You can create your own connector. Confluent Platform is not required but is very helpful.